# cocos2d-x game slows down while showing effect of CCParticleExplosion

Tags: cocos2d-x, ccparticlesystem

I am using     `this->schedule( schedule_selector(HelloWorld::Game), 0.01);`

and in my game play function game slows down due to following code

```
CCTexture2D* texture = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->textureForKey("CloseSelected.png");
                CCParticleExplosion* firework = CCParticleExplosion::create();
                firework->setTexture(texture);
                firework->setPosition(ccp(((CCSprite *) shipLaser)->getPositionX(),((CCSprite *) shipLaser)->getPositionY()));
addChild(firework);
```

whenever the explosion effect take place the game remains slow.

1. another thing how I can reduce the radius of explosion ?
   Thanks

Comment: on a device? which one? do you create this effect 100 times per second perhaps since it sounds you run this code on a schedule?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D no this effect does not created 100 times per second it only creates when fire hits the object only. Schedule checks that either bullet fire intersects the enemy object or not and when it touches the object the Explosion effect took place which slows down the game speed until the effect vanishes.